¿Conocen algún Poema Yámbico?
¿Conocen algún poema enteramente yámbico en español? (Es decir, que cada uno de los versos esté compuesto por pies yámbicos).
pd: Sé que es muy difícil lograr eso en español.

Mi querida
En noches claras pienso en tu mirar,
Tus ojos son estrellas en mi mar.
Te quiero tanto, más que al propio ser,
Mi vida sin tu amor no puede ser.
Tus labios son la miel que quiero yo,
Tus manos, suaves, son mi fiel calor.
Te quiero tanto, más que al cielo azul,
Mi corazón por ti late sin fin.
En cada amanecer, tu luz me da,
La fuerza para amar, para soñar.
Te quiero tanto, más que a la razón,
Eres mi vida, mi alma, mi canción.

La fuerza para amar, para soñar.
tiene acento en la séptima sílaba "para" dejando la octava en ritmo débil. Por lo tanto no es estrictamente yámbico.
También en el primer verso, cuando pones "tu mirar", el "tu" es la octava sílaba y está en ritmo débil.
Entiendo que uno puede intentar cuadrar y hacer composiciones yámbicas pero me refería a si existía un poema yámbico de algún autor profesional. La repetición del segundo y tercer verso del verbo "ser" es redundante.
Gracias de todas formas por tu respuesta
